# How to Stretch Jasper Table Columns based on Content

Tags: jasper-reports

In jasper report (iReport 4.5) I need to make all table fit it's content width,
Image below show how columns contain spaces which not needed

I tried "Stretch Type" to be "Relative to tallest object" but not work

[image]

Comment: PDF file formated

Comment: The width is fixed for this format

Comment: Are you mean that PDF format can't be stretched to column size, In that case how can I adjust column size to fit string length.

Comment: `Stretch type` only affects height.

Comment: What's affect width in case of PDF format

Comment: As @AlexK said, PDF width is fixed. No width change in PDF. Not possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities for dynamic widths using PDF formats. All of these possibilities will likely involve developing custom software. It can be done, but it isn't trivial. Here are a few ways, though the column does not "stretch" per se -- the width of the column must be known before the report template is created.

It's possible to calculate the width of the column if you know the content and the font attributes (family, weight, size, etc.) in advance.

## Dynamic Template

Since JRXML files have a straightforward format, it is possible to write a shell script, batch program, or application to generate `.jrxml` files. This allows complete control over page and column widths. The Java code will have to compile the `.jrxml` file before the corresponding `.jasper` file can be filled.

## Dynamic Jasper

Use [Dyanmic Jasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/) to create reports with dynamic widths.